# Dialog box to select option from list in Python on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, dialog, pywin32

I need to create a dialog box that allows user to select one option from a list in Python on Windows using PyWin32 library. PyWin32 has a DialogBox function, but I cannot find any examples how to use it and I never used it before. Could anybody give me some advice?

The window should be something similar to the one below - this has been created using Zenity (scroll bar is unneeded, this has been added by Zenity itself; I'm perfectly fine with a window that just lists the options - there will be no more than about 5-6 of them), but I would rather like to avoid using external tools like Zenity, I also cannot install other libraries on the system except PyWin32 that is already installed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have to reply to myself :). Within the directory where PyWin32 is installed, there is a file `pythonwin\pywin\dialogs\list.py` that contains a sample class `ListDialog` implementing exactly such a dialog. It can be either used directly "as is", with some code like following:

```
import pywin.dialogs.list

result=pywin.dialogs.list.SelectFromList('Select level', ['standard', 'advanced', 'expert'])
print(result)
```

or it can be copied to a separate file and modified to change the style/layout/behavior of the window and imported from the modified file.